# Using functions with express.js "locals"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Coming from a Rails/Sinatra background, I won't feel at home without being able to use helper functions in my view files, however achieving this in express.js has proven quite difficult.

You can set [locals](http://expressjs.com/api#app.locals) to be automatically included like this...

```
app.set("name", "Adam's App");
```

Then in the view file, accessing the variable is as simple as:

```
<!-- views/template.ejs -->
<title><%= settings.name %></title>
```

But what about for functions? What if I want to have a `date_helper` function in my views? I tried setting it like you would a variable...

```
app.set("date_helper", function(timestamp){ ... });
```

...however calling `<%= settings.date_helper %>` won't execute the function (obviously), let alone enable me to pass the `timestamp` argument to it.

Am I going about this the right way?

Comment: When you render it, do you try passing the function directly?  `.render('something', { settings: app.settings, helper: function(){...} }, function (err, stuff) {...});` along those lines ish

Comment: @Deryck I haven't needed to use `settings: app.settings` (I think that's been deprecated in express 3.0?). That aside - my aim here is to have access to these functions without having to specify it in the `.render` block. It seems pretty lame having to use `date_helper: function(){..}` in every route I define, agreed?

Comment: Yeah I was just saying as a troubleshooting option but the answer below me actually has it.  I was going to suggest the `app.locals.date_helper` assignment but looks like his is better than what I was gonna say lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set view variables at the [app level](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.locals), the [response level](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.locals), and/or [at the time of render](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.render).

So you could combine these and do something like:

```
app.locals.date_helper = function(ts) {
  return (new Date(ts)).toISOString();
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('main', { timestamp: 1406809421643 });
});
```

Then inside your template:

`The date is: <%= date_helper(timestamp) %>`

On a semi-related note, you should be aware of [special view variable names](https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs/#options) used by ejs.

Comment: Cool. Doesn't `app.set(x)` do exactly the same thing as `app.locals.x` though?

Comment: You probably could use that, but then you have to do things like `settings.date_helper(timestamp)` in your views. `app.set()`/`app.get()`/`settings` should generally be used for application settings only, not adding helpers and other similar view-specific things.

Comment: Mhmmm. Suppose you had an object with helper functions to set: `var helpers = { date_helper: function(){...}, name_helper: function(){...} }`. If we were to loop through each kv pair in the object to set each one, would it be possible to set them using `app.locals`?

Comment: I currently do it with `app.set` using: `Object.keys(helpers).forEach(function(helper) { app.set(helper, helpers[helper]) });`

Comment: Yes, you could do something similar for `app.locals`: `Object.keys(helpers).forEach(function(helper) { app.locals[helper] = helpers[helper] });`

Answer (score 0):

use app middleware

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals = {
        test: 'Sample Test',
        test_function: (name) => {
            return 'Hello ' + name;
        }
    }
    next();
});
```

in view you can use

```
<%= test %> // output = " Sample test "
<%= test_function("Abdo") %> // output = " Hello Abdo"
```